# Iterating through a list for specific instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
paths = [['E', 'D', 'A', 'B'], ['E', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B'], ['E', 'D', 'B'], ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B'], ['E', 'B'], ['E', 'C', 'B']]
```

Now, the lists inside a list represent node paths from start to end which were made using Networkx, however that is some background information. My question is more specific.

I am trying to derive the lists that only have every letter from A-E, aka it would return only the list:

```
paths_desired = [['E', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B']]
```

If I were to have another path:

```
paths = [['E', 'D', 'A', 'B'], ['E', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B'], ['D', 'B', 'A','C','E'], ['A', 'D', 'C', 'B']]
```

It would return:

```
paths_desired = [['E', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B'],['D', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'E']]
```

My idea is a for loop that iterates through each list:

```
for i in pathways:
    counter = 0
    for j in letters:
        if j in i:
            counter = counter + 1;
    if counter == 5:
        desired_paths.append(i)
        
print(desired_paths)
```

This works, however, I want to make the loop more specific, meaning I want only lists that have the following order: ['E','D','A','C','B'], even if all the letters are present in a different list, within the paths list.

Additionally, is there a way I can upgrade my for loop, so that I wouldn't count, rather check if the letters are in there, and not more than 1 of each letter? Meaning no multiple Es, no multiple D, etc.

Comment: If there are never duplicates, all you need is `len(i) == 5`.  Right?

Comment: Or `len(set(i))` to drop duplicates?

Comment: I am confused by now.  If you want the exact list, including the order, why not check list equality?  Your question would be easier to figure out if you stated all the requirements up front, gave sample input, with expected output, along with your code so far and (incorrect results).  This format, where you state *some* requirements, show code, show results, and then go, wait... that's not the only thing, I also want X Y and Z, **at the end**, without sample data or expectations is confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a use a `set` and `.issubset()` like this:

```
def pathways(letters, paths):
    ret = []
    letters = set(letters)
    for path in paths:
        if letters.issubset(path):
            ret.append(path)
    return ret


letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
paths = [['E', 'D', 'A', 'B'], ['E', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
         ['D', 'B', 'A','C','E'], ['A', 'D', 'C', 'B']]
print(pathways(letters, paths))  # => [['E', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B'], ['D', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'E']]
```

Also, as a comment by [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) pointed out, the `pathways()` function could be shortened using `filter()`. Like this:

```
def pathways(letters, paths):
    return list(filter(set(letters).issubset, paths))


letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
paths = [['E', 'D', 'A', 'B'], ['E', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
         ['D', 'B', 'A','C','E'], ['A', 'D', 'C', 'B']]
print(pathways(letters, paths))
```